# RxJava .zip() raw type?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to `zip` two observables together.First is of type `Single<SomeClass>` and second is `Observable<SomeOtherClass>`. However, in `.zip()` function the return types does not get cast to correct classes, I get raw types (`T1`,`T2`). Example:

```
Single<SomeClass> o1 = ....
Observable<SomeOtherClass> o2 = ....

Observable.zip(o1,o2, (u,u2) -> ...) // here I get 2 raw types
```

And if I try this way (since I am "zipping" 2 observables only):

```
 o1.zipWith(o2, (someClass, u) -> ...) //here only o1 is cast to class instance
```

If I try `Observable.zip(Observable.range(...),Observable.interval(...), (integer,long) -> ...)` I get the correct casts.

I can't figure out why it won't cast to my class objects in my example above, any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use a Single as an input parameter to Observable.zip, it doesn't really make sense to as the function is called with incoming pairs, a single will only give one result so the function would only get called once with the result of the Single and first result from the Observable. You could achieve that by calling toObservable() on your single, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zip() you get a few objects in input, and transform them to something different in OUT.
So you need to specify some output type:

```
Observable.zip(o1, o2, (u1,u2) -> new NewOtherClass(u1, u2))
```

In the example above the compiler know that return type for your lambda is `NewOtherClass`.

Note, that Single and Observable can't be used in the same chain with no additional transformation (note `.toObservable()` below):

```
 Observable.zip(o1.toObservable(), o2, (u1,u2) -> /*return do something*/)
```